# Handling multiple ads sources (adMob + Leadbolt) on Android

Tags: android, admob, ads, leadbolt

i'm new with Android and i've been playing with it a bit in the past few weeks. I've been following some tutorials and most of them explains the ad theme with adMob, which is an obvious solution to use because is made by the same enterprise that made the OS. However, i've been searching for some others solutions and a friend recommended me Leadbolt, i've downloaded the sdk to use it, but another idea came up to my mind, i came from .NET and on ASP.NET there's the adrotator control, that i could use to display ads from several sources  there isn't anything similar that do that on android? If not there's another solution to use both ads on a same space on the app? I have it as a Banner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a Mediation solution where you can configure (server-side) how to distribute requests to different ads from multiple ad networks.  If one network doesn't fill the request, then the mediation solution would try one of your other configured networks.

The AdMob SDK now includes mediation since v6.0. You can learn more about AdMob Mediation [here](http://support.google.com/admob/answer/2413211?hl=en) and how to integrate it [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation#android).

Comment: Seems as a solution to me for what i read in their overview, however, it seems they only have the option Ad Network Mediation for people living on USA (not my case), I've downloaded the SDK without problems. Thanks, let's see how can I solve the geographic stuff.

Comment: Where are you reading that it only supports US?  You currently have to request to be included in the Mediation Beta.  AdMob is looking to open it up by default soon.

Comment: To be complete, there are other Mediation solutions out there.  I don't know too much about most of them though, and how they compare.  One other solution I do know about is [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/), which is an open-source solution.  But AdMob Mediation is planned to be the next generation of AdWhirl, so I wouldn't recommend it if you are just getting started with one of these products.

Comment: Ok, got it now that i have to make a request, thought that the request was just to get the SDK. Agree with you that if AdMob Mediation would be something like the next version of AdWhirl it doesn't make too much sense to use the latter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag Google Admob and Leadbolt SDK integration is possible on android activity? Can u please tell me its possible or not?

Comment: @Sam_k Leadbolt is not integrated directly (they haven't written an adapter for AdMob Mediation) but it's possible to for you to integrate the Leadbolt network via a custom event. Check out this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/training/mediation/custom-events/banners) on how to set up a custom event, and adapt it to request a leadbolt ad.

Comment: I also updated the answer, AdMob Mediation has been public since the v6.0 release in late April 2012. Anybody can create a mediation placement ad mediation.admob.com and upgrade their app to use AdMob mediation.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag Thanks for Your reply but Here i am asking Different thing to you, My question is this Can i use both leadbolt and admob both in my application separatly? I am not asking about both integration, individually can i use both types of adds?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "separately"?

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag Can u please help me to figure out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440284/google-admob-sdk-replacement-issue-in-android-application Please