# Google Admob SDK replacement issue in android application

Tags: android, admob, google-ad-manager

I have one android application and this application uses Google admob  `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0` version. Now i wants to update my google admob SDK.

This is the message on google admob site [Here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid).

```
We are deprecating all SDK versions that were released in 2010 or earlier. For Android, this includes any SDK released on or before November 9, 2010. If your code references com.admob.android.ads.*, then you will need to update your SDK.
```

I am just try to replace this `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0` version to `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1` .

But i am getting error regarding import about `com.admob.android.ads.*` this.

Please let me know the solution regarding this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.admob.android.ads.*` references old AdMob SDKs released in 2010 or earlier. If your app was only using `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0`, you should only have references to `com.google.ads.*`.

To can check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android-targeting) for how to set location. You'll use `com.google.ads.AdRequest#setLocation(location)`. However, AdMob recommends that you only pass location in your AdRequest if your app already makes use of location, since it requires adding  extra permissions in your app.

Comment: This link gives the iphone example. So what short of changes i have to do in my code? i used above code which i mentioned in question so what i have to do please let me know i am really frustted with this error :(

Comment: Can u please suggest me the way i am really stuck up

Comment: Can u please check my updated question and please help me out

Comment: Unfortunately the links show the iOS tab by default, so click the Android tab and the #hashtag link should work.

Comment: It looks like you're completely referencing the old AdMob API. You'll want to check out the getting started guide (here)[https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals] (remember to click android tab) to see how to set up the Google AdMob Ads SDK.

Comment: You can also download the basic Android sample app [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/downloads/detail?name=Android_Fundamentals.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges) which basically replicates the code from the getting started guide. Just stick in the v6.3.1 SDK into the libs directory of that project, and swap in  your AdMob publisher ID, and you should have a working ads example.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply.I have one question is it necessary to set location programatically? i can not use `<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />` ?  May be this is use for location automatically? am i right?

Comment: That doesn't work with the Google AdMob SDK - that seems to have been the legacy AdMob way of setting location.